# Move a player to a specific room

Tags: python

I have an adventure game that i am creating for a beginner class.  The only real issue i have is that if they don't have an item, it still lets them move forward.

Ex: you are at the weeds, you need a soda to move forward.  I trap this and tell the player that and so i thought I could send them directly to the room that the item they need is located.

code:

```
'soda' not in inventory:
print("You did a great job clearing the weeds, but...")
print("You need a soda from the Snack shack to move forward")
#send player to Snack shack
current_room['name'] = rooms['Snack shack'] #current_room is variable used to move players
print("You are in the {}".format(current_room['name']))
print("You found {}".format(current_room['item']))
I = input("You will need it at some point, pick it up? (Y/N)")
     if I == 'Y':
        inventory.append(current_room['item'])
        print("Your current inventory is:", inventory)
        print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
```

Output:

```
    You are in Weeds2.
    You did a great job clearing the weeds, but...
    You need a soda from the Snack shack to move forward
    You are in the {'name': 'Snack shack', 'North': 'Tulip sanctuary', 'East': Guard shack', 'item': 'soda', 'count': 2}
    You found none
    You will need it at some point, pick it up? (Y/N)

    expect this - You are in the {'name': 'Snack shack', 'North': 'Tulip sanctuary', 'East': Guard shack', 'item': 'soda', 'count': 2}
    You found none

    to say - You are in the Snack shack
    You found soda
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @Barmar I just submitted an edit that makes the code more clear.

Comment: `current_room['name'] = rooms['Snack shack']` should be `current_room = rooms['Snack shack']`

Comment: @barmar - Thanks first post, thought it posted it clearly.

Comment: @Barmar THANKS, something simple, always... Dang

Comment: You had an image of the code, I thought it was duplicating the snippet of code that you posted, so I removed it.